# Geometric series summation with power which is also geometric.

Tags: geometric-series, nested-radicals

I was just pondering how will this series converge. Assuming $n \ge 0$, find
$$
f(n)=n^{1/2} + n^{1/4} + n^{1/8} + n^{1/16} +\text{...}+  1
$$
We stop the summation when we hit $1$ i.e. $\lfloor{n^{1/2^k}}\rfloor=1$

I tested how quickly the number converges i.e. how many items until its 1. It seems like it converges pretty quickly and the total sum is $O(\sqrt n)$ since I verified for the number $10^{10}$ and the computer returned $100341$(summing after taking the floor of the intermediate values).

It may be pretty easy problem but can't seem to find a way to derive a formula out of this. Any insights would be great. Thank you.

Comment: This is a series where the power itself is geometric. So kinda different from the normal geometric series.

Comment: So basically we are summing up the square root, square root of square root, and so on until the number converges to 1.

Comment: The number $n^{1/2^k}$ never reaches $1$, only approaches it, so when exactly do you stop?

Comment: @MichalAdamaszek Haha nice question, although mathematically it should converge to $n^0=1$,

Comment: @MichalAdamaszek Whenever it reaches $n^{1/2^k} \lt 2$, we can just stop since we have reached the desired point at least for me where the floor of the value is always 1.

Comment: Then you have $\log_2(\log_2(n))$ terms and the sum is at most $n^{1/2}+n^{1/4}\log \log(n)$ so indeed $\Theta(\sqrt{n})$ like you claimed.

Comment: @MichalAdamaszek Damn is this that straightforward, I must be having brain fog or something. Can't seem to understand how you found $log_ 2(n)$

Comment: Is the series infinite ? If yes, it does not converge for $n\ge 1$.

Comment: @Peter Actually, I am trying to use the intuition to solve another problem where we build a numbering system out of these roots.

Comment: Take $\log_2$ twice in $n^{1/2^k}<2$ to solve for $k$

Comment: Added clarifications for whether series is infinite or not(its not, we stop when we hit < 2$.

Comment: For large $n$ , the first term dominates all the others , therefore it is already a good approximation of $f(n)$